# byte[] to iresourcestream in Wicket

Tags: java, xml, ajax, stream, wicket

I would like to implement the example of [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/ajax-update-and-file-download-in-one-blow.html).

I'm stuck at the `getResourceStream()` method. My application has a `byte[]` (generated XML file), that users should be able to download. The problem is that I don't know how to convert a `byte[]` to `IResourceStream`.

This is what I have:

```
final AJAXDownload download = new AJAXDownload()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected IResourceStream getResourceStream()
    {
        ByteArrayResource bar = new ByteArrayResource("TEXT??", xmlFileInBytes);
                return (IResourceStream) bar;
        }
    };
```

The code above gives a `ClassCastException`. Can someone explain how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the class StringResourceStream which is a child of IResourceStream and to use the byte array:

You can do something like this:

```
  byte byteArray[] = new byte[1024]   //this is the byte array containing the xml which you want to use.
  StringResourceStream srs = new StringResourceStream(new String(byteArray));
```

So in your case the method will look something like below:

```
 final AJAXDownload download = new AJAXDownload()
 {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Override
     protected IResourceStream getResourceStream()
     {
         StringResourceStream bar = new StringResourceStream (new String(xmlFileInBytes) );
                 return (IResourceStream) bar;
         }
     };
```

Comment: Your answer was to fast for the system, I had to wait a few minutes ;) Now its marked as accepted

Comment: This is a terrible solution. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[]%29): *"The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified."* In other words, if you don't have prior knowledge of whether bytes indeed represents a valid string in the platforms default charset, the downloadable content is *undefined*. This is especially bad since it may work on your development machine, and break in production.

Answer (score 2):

The class `ByteArrayResource` implements `IResource`, but not `IResourceStream`. That why you have the `ClassCastException`.

To solve it, you should find a class that implements `IResourceStream`; see it's [Javadoc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/org/apache/wicket/util/resource/IResourceStream.html) for a list of possible implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code at the moment, but instead of doing

```
ByteArrayResource bar = new ByteArrayResource("TEXT??", xmlFileInBytes);
return (IResourceStream) bar;
```

you could try [`getResourceStream`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/resource/ByteArrayResource.html#getResourceStream%28%29) as follows:

```
ByteArrayResource bar = new ByteArrayResource("TEXT??", xmlFileInBytes);
return bar.getResourceStream();
```